# What is the path of the cache directory on Android and iOS?

Tags: react-native

I need to insert the path of the cache directory, that the image will be saved on android and iOS, by the library, but I don't know which path this is. Can someone please tell me which way it is?

```js
export const openImage = (setFunc, w, h) => {
  ImagePicker.openPicker({
    cropping: true,
    path: "INSERT PATH HERE",
    mediaType: 'photo',
    width: p42(w) * 2.5,
    height: p42(h) * 2.5,
  })
    .then(response => {
      // alert(JSON.stringify(response));
      setFunc(response.path);
    })
    .catch(error => console.log('>>>>', error))
    .finally(() => ImagePicker.clean());
};
```

Comment: I think in `path` you need to pass the image's path which you want to crop.

Comment: No! Path is the exit path. If I don't put that path it saves it in the user gallery, and I don't want that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [react-native-fs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fs) for that.

`CachesDirectoryPath (String)` The absolute path to the caches directory

`ExternalCachesDirectoryPath (String)` The absolute path to the external caches directory (**android only**)